# "Going to + Present Simple" vs "Going to + Present Continuous"

Tags: present-continuous, future-time, present-simple

I am interested in distinguishing the difference between two patterns *(to speak about a future plans, intentions, predictions, or intent to do something)*:

1. **Going to + Present Simple**
2. **Going to + Present Continuous**

I know both patterns and use them, however, I am not anymore sure what the exact distinction is between them. However, I am aware that **Going to + Present Continuous** cannot be used to **Issue Commands** unlike **Going to + Present Simple**:

- You are **going to collect** your right now! **(Correct)**
- You are **going to be collecting** your toys right now! **(Incorrect)**

Other examples where I cannot distinguish the difference:

- I am **going to have** a party next week.
- I am **going to be having** a party next week.

---

- We are **going to carry out** an experiment today.
- We are **going to be carrying out** an experiment today.

Comment: Neither would I use to issue a command. I would just use the imperative "Collect you toy!". However, I think it's OK with negative, "You are not going to do that!"

Comment: I think this article will help you a lot : http://english.blogoverflow.com/2015/09/how-we-talk-about-future-situations/

Comment: @dz420 there's nothing about "Going to + Present Continuous"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the activity can be cast as one that recurs or is ongoing, the periphrasis for the future (BE + going) *can* be coupled with the continuous/progressive:

> I'm going to **be attending** a conference in Chicago in July. We should try to get together. It would be great to catch up with you.

There, choosing the continuous  over "going to *attend*" suggests that there may be *several* days on which an opportunity to get together may present itself.

Comment: So "**She's going to be having a baby**" is absolutely wrong?

Comment: **having a baby** is something "continuous". The baby doesn't just pop out like a cork from a champagne bottle.  *Why is that lady screaming, mommy? -- She's having a baby.*

Comment: Then "**She's going to have a baby**" means that one day she'll give birth?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that **to have** there refers to the birth as something that will **happen** rather than as a process she will **undergo**.  You must understand that these are nuances the speaker might not be fully conscious of when choosing between verb forms.