# future continuous vs be going to be do something

Tags: future-continuous

We use future continuous when:

1. two actions happen at the same time (I will be singing while she is cooking)
2. longer action interrupted by a shorter one (I will be driving when she comes)
3. future arrangements (I will be working tomorrow)
4. for temporary actions (Next week we will be using bikes instead of cars)
5. for processes (I will be getting taller and taller)
6. when we specify time like for 2 hours or in the morning

Does the construction "be going to be doing" work the same as future continuous? I named 6 uses of future continuous. Can we replace them all with "be going to be doing"?

Comment: Where did you get this list from? I don't recognize #4 "for **temporary** actions". To me, nothing about the *syntax* of the example *Next week we **will be using** bikes instead of cars* implies "temporary" apart from the fact that initial ***next week*** might be understood to mean ***during** next week* rather than ***by** next week*.

Comment: #3 *I will be working tomorrow* is quite a common alternative to *I will work tomorrow*, but that's not really because it's a "future arrangement". It's because ***working*** is so inherently an ***extended action***. But see [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tomorrow+I+will+be+going%2CTomorrow+I+will+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing how uncommon *Tomorrow I will be going...* is compared to *Tomorrow I will go...* And offhand I can't of *any* context where the former would be "better". You don't need it.

Comment: What about be going to be doing?

Comment: This feels like the main question has gotten buried under the list. In fact, maybe the *real* question is, "When can/should we replace simple future 'I will X' with 'I am going to X'"? Because once you solve that, it's just a matter of adding the -ing! I wonder whether there's a duplicate of that question already here...

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/133182/138287 as well as https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/246277/138287

Comment: See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+be+doing+it%2Cwill+be+doing+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing how ***going to be doing it*** has started to gain traction as an alternative to ***will be doing it***. But also note [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+be+doing+it%2Cwill+be+doing+it%2Cwill+do+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing how uncommon *both* of them are compared to Simple Future ***will do it***. If you don't *know* you need the continuous, don't use it!